# How can I create a dynamic query in Amplify Datastore

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datastore, aws-amplify

How do i create a dynamic query in amplify react application

Expected Query:

```
const posts = await DataStore.query(Post, c => c.or(
  c => c.rating("gt", 4).status("eq", PostStatus.PUBLISHED)
));
```

'rating' and 'status' may change depends on user. Please help me to create a dynamic datastore query.

Comment: Could you post another example of a dynamically generated query?

Comment: @johannchopin - I need to change the filter query based on my schema. for eg: For user A it is rating and status. For user B it may be active and status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let just say you have an object which defines what user can use what filter queries. Here I assumed user can be of two types typeA and typeB.

```
const queryTable = {
    typeA: ['status', 'rating'],
    typeB: ['active', 'status']
}

const posts = await DataStore.query(Post, c => c.or(
    c => {
        const operator = "eq" || "gt";
        const value = 4 || "published";
        queryTable[user.type].forEach(func, => {
            c.[func](operator, value)
        })
        return c
    }
));
```

You have to figure out a way how you can pass operator and value.

Comment: This line `const operator = "eq" || "gt";` will always evaluate to `eq`. Same with `const value = 4 || "published"` it will be `4`

Comment: Yeah I know but that was sort of an example saying he can use wither eq or gt or whatever he likes as an operator. Same with value as well.

Comment: @Karthik: Thank you for the query, its worked.  Also How do we handle AND and OR query together. Please advice